# Do workflow outbound messages (OBM) and @future methods share a single message queue for asynchronous processing?

Tags: asynchronous, workflowoutboundmessage

Do workflow outbound messages (OBM) and @future methods both share a single message queue for asynchronous processing?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so:

based on [Salesforce Docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_invoking_future_methods.htm) Future Methods share the asynchronous Apex resources (and limits) with *Batch Apex*, *Queueable Apex* and *Scheduled Apex*.

Outbound Messages don't have any daily limit, have an auto-retry mechanism for 24h, and they're also monitored in a different section under **Setup > Monitor > Outbound Messages**.